# How to get the text between angular brackets but without the angular brackets?

Tags: regex, delphi-10.3-rio

I have tried this:

```
(?=<).+(?<=>)
```

But it always matches the angular brackets too:

[image]

So how can I get the text without the brackets? (it should match any text between the brackets which fits in a line).

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to match?

Comment: What yare you trying to match "diaris" or "sad.exe" ?

Comment: Textual information is usually preferred in textual shape. Showing the highlighting is something of a reason to show a picture, put please also give the text.

Comment: Is it possible that "<" or ">" are inside what should be matched? E.g. "<di<>aris>" which should match "di<>aris". I.e. please describe all the possible things to match. Would it be sufficient to only match characters and digits?

Comment: No, it should match anything. But I cannot write it in the question because so changes the text.

Comment: What you're trying to match is text. There is no reason for a sample of that text to not be in your post. You can't copy/paste from an image for testing. In fact, I can't see your sample  text because imgur is blocked by my corporate proxy, so I can't even read your question as written because of your inappropriate use of an image to present textual content.

Comment: @KenWhite That has to do with the impossibility to escape so control characters like lesser-than.

Comment: I don't understand why that has anything to do with you posting an image instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy, the `.+` eats up everything up to the end of the line (remember, the dot matches everything including `>` and `<` here).
Either use a lazy quantifier ([**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fqWSjv/1))

```
(?<=<).+?(?=>)
```

or a negated character class ([**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fqWSjv/2))

```
<([^>]+)
```

Comment: Thanks, the first example works as I want. But what if the text between the angular brackets is "dia>ris"?

Comment: @user1580348 you should specify multiple strings (and expected results) in your question so that we can help you with a proper regex pattern to match (or not match) them. As it stands, there is only one string and one rule that was presented and matching `dia>ris` goes against the rules you gave us in your question.

Comment: How to escape the lesser-than character in the question?

Comment: @user1580348 If the <> can contain >, then you need a way to accurately determine which > is your actual ending. That may not be a job for regex, though; regex is not suitable for actual parsing files, since it cannot detect matching brackets in bracket hierarchies.