# Regular Expression to extract strings between angle brackets with exactly one @ char in between

Tags: php, regex

Does any one have an idea how to match something like

```
<t@t.com>
```

I tried this regular expression

```
\<(.?*)\>
```

but this matches also `<sddsds>` I want it to match where inside `<>` is an email with `@` sign.

Comment: Just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) and add <> around it

Comment: The art of programming is breaking problems down - don't expect to find someone who's written the exact code you need, but do look for sub-problems that might be common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
<([^<>@]+@[^<>@]+)>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CTdbro/3). *Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `([^<>@]+@[^<>@]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `<`, `>` and `@`, a `@` char and then again any one or more chars other than `<`, `>` and `@`
- `>` - a `>` char.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/AQKWT):

```php
$str = "<t@t.com>\n<tatacom>\n<t@ata@com>";
$re = '/<([^<>@]+@[^<>@]+)>/';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
// => Array( [0] => t@t.com )
```

Comment: can we match only one @

Comment: @user3150060 Yes, see the current answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but shouldn't we add + at the end of send bracket be at least one or more Chars?

Comment: @OmarAbdelaziz I do not know why the `*` found its way into the pattern, I meant the `+` from the very beginning.

Comment: Sure, you presented a very clean regex

Comment: A valid email may contain a `@` in the user portion of the address if it is wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`$regex = '/^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/'`

Comment: I'm not sure what the `[,-]` sections are trying to do.  `-` is not special in an email address.  And you're assuming all top-level domains have 2 or 3 letters, which is not true (.info, .news, etc).  Plus, `\w` is far too restrictive; email addresses allow more than that.  `*` is valid, for example.  In general, matching email address is FAR more difficult than most people think.